# Add Comments column in Windows Explorer on multiple machines

Tags: c#, registry, windows-explorer

I would like to add the "Comments" column to the Details view of Windows Explorer on multiple machines (for everyone at my company).  I understand how to do that on a single machine by adding the column then applying it to all folders.  What I'm looking for is a program or script to do this so I can push it to all users.

I compared registry entries before and after adding the column and found this key:
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3777224697-1282845601-4005622287-2612\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes{FBB3477E-C9E4-4B3B-A2BA-D3F5D3CD46F9}\TopViews{82BA0782-5B7A-4569-B5D7-EC83085F08CC}]

has a value: "ColumnList" that appears to hold the new column name on some versions of Windows.  That method does not seem to work on all flavors of Windows, and it modifies the behavior for only a specific user.

Comment: Is this really a programming question?  Can you demonstrate how this is specifically a programming question (C#, according to your label) and not a windows question that belongs on http://superuser.com/?

Comment: C# was recommended as a tag when I posted the question.  As C# is one of the primary tools for modifying the registry, I accepted the suggestion.  I have searched for existing tools unsuccessfully and believe that this can only be solved by writing a program.  At this point I don't know what tool would be most appropriate; perhaps C# is not the best tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what I wanted.  Also the "Comments" column stopped working correctly starting with Vista, so this would have very limited value even if it did work.